# What Drupal WYSIWYG editors work well with Safari?

Tags: drupal, safari

My site contributors are primarily Safari on Mac users.  We're running into issues with CKEditor and Safari dumping a bunch of nested spans into the html created by changing content.  The html eventually gets so big and ugly that Safari can take up to 10 minutes to display it.  The drupal pages that are affected are ones that the authors are modifying, new content is fine.  The pages also seem to have a lot of tables in them.  Can anyone recommend an editor that doesn't have this behavior in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what features you want to have this can differ. But closest to CKEditor is tinyMCE as WYSIWYG editor. there is ready to go code for drupal and it has a large community.

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/

Comment: I'm willing to offer a subset of functionality if the editor plays nice with Safari.  Have you used tinyMCE in Safari?

Comment: yes, I've used tinyMCE several projects (all public websites) that needed to support IE7/8/9, Opera, Firefox and safari. The only problem I found was image resizing in a beta of chrome. I submitted a bug and it was fixed not more then a month later.